# Is there accepted notation for this remainder function

Tags: notation

I have a use for a function that represents the least amount that must be added to an integer $x$ to make it a multiple of $y$.

I.e., if we call that function $\Delta$, then $\Delta(\frac{x}{y}) = y\lceil\frac{x}{y}\rceil-x$

If there isn't an accepted notation, should I use the Delta symbol or an abbreviation, such as "def" for "deficit" or "dif" for "difference"? And is it clearer to express it in the form $\Delta(\frac{x}{y})$ or $\Delta(x,y)$?

For my purpose $x$ and $y$ will always be mutually prime, and positive.

Comment: It is definitely wrong to write it as $\Delta(\frac xy)$, since it depends on the integers $x$ and $y$ separately, not just on the rational number $\frac xy$.

Comment: So, you have three quantities:  the smaller integer, the larger integer, and the "bump" to the larger integer that makes it a multiple of the smaller integer.   To help the reader, I would recommend we refer to these quantities as $n$, $N$, and $b_n(N)$.  [With this notation, $0 \leq b_n(N) < n \leq N$ .]

Comment: @SelrachDunbar The bump may be greater than or equal to the smaller integer, e.g. $x=2$, $y = 5$, $\Delta = 3$.

Comment: @peterwhy I see.  I intended the notation to denote that $0 < n \leq N$. In this case the bump we need to give the larger integer (i.e. "the bump of the larger integer") is as above.   If we want to consider the bump we need to give the smaler integer it would be, as you pointed out $b_N(n) = N-n$.   Thanks!

Comment: @peterwhy  In fact, your answer shows that, if $0<n \leq N$ then $b_n(N)= n - (N \bmod n)$.

Comment: @SelrachDunbar Yes, that was in revision 1, which I did not like, because a special case is when $N\bmod n = 0$ then $b_n(N) = 0$.

Comment: @peterwhy  Yes.  The condition in my last comment needs to be $0<n<N$ for that formula to work.  I like your updated answer which gives a single expression for $b_n(N)=(-N) \bmod n$ which works for any $0<n, \, N \in \mathbb{N}$ (regardless of which is bigger).

Comment: Must the increment $\delta$ be nonnegative, e.g. for $\,x,y = 6,5\,$ is $\,\delta = 4\ $ or $\,-1$ (least *magnitude*). Either way it has obvious expression in terms of $\bmod = $ remainder.

Comment: @SelrachDunbar $0<n<N$ is not sufficient, as $N$ could be a multiple of $n$ and then $N\bmod n = 0$.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: yes, I need it to be the least positive number such that adding it to x makes x a multiple of y.

Comment: @JoeSlater So $\,\delta$ can't be $0,\,$ i.e. if $\, x\,$ is a multiple of $\,y\,$ then you add $\,\delta =y\,$ instead of $\,\delta = 0?\ \ $

Comment: No, sorry, I should have said "least non-negative" number I suppose. I.e., 0 >= δ < x

Answer (score 2):

When performing division with remainder:

$$n = dq+r$$

where $0\le r <d$ and $r$ is sometimes denoted $n \bmod d$, so

$$n = d\left\lfloor\frac nd\right\rfloor + (n\bmod d)$$

Consider dividing $-x$ by $y$ with remainder,

$$\begin{align*}
-x &= y\left\lfloor \frac{-x}{y}\right\rfloor + (-x \bmod y)\\
&= -y\left\lceil\frac xy\right\rceil + (-x\bmod y)\\
y\left\lceil\frac xy\right\rceil - x &= (-x) \bmod y\\
\Delta &= (-x) \bmod y
\end{align*}$$

---

An alternative view, $\Delta$ is a number that satisfy both $0\le \Delta < y$ and

$$\begin{align*}
x + \Delta &= ky\\
x + \Delta &\equiv 0 \pmod y\\
\Delta &\equiv -x \pmod y
\end{align*}$$

Then $\Delta$ is just $(-x)\bmod y$.

Answer (score -1):

@JoeSlater  In terms of your original question.  After the above discussion in the comments, I would recommend, as a notation $b_y(x)$ to represent the "bump of $x$ you need to make it a multiple of $y$."  As @peterwhy has shown in his answer above, this quantity is given by the expression:

$$b_y(x)=(-x) \bmod y$$

for all positive integers $x$ and $y$.

(So, if you don't mind writing a little more, you could just write this expression every time you need to refer to this quantity.)

Comment: From what I understand, expressing numbers as "x mod y" reflects older programming languages' implementation of the "modulo" function, not the mathematical definition. What "x mod y" returns is actually a class of numbers: ...  x-2y, x-y, x, x+y, x+2y ..., so "-x mod y" wouldn't work as a definition without stipulating that it was confined to the least positive value.

Comment: @JoeSlater Yes.  In mathematics, as you have stated, "x mod y" represents a class of numbers.  (Actually, this operation breaks the integers up into y "equivalence classes".)  I suspect a computer, is going to be very efficient and store the output euqivalence class as exactly the representative of that equivalence class you want, i.e. the least positive value (or 0) that is in that equivalence calss.